# A specific Schwartz function $f$ on $\mathbb C^2$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Choose a Schwartz function on $\mathbb C$ of the form $f(z)=f(r e^{i\theta})= f_0(r) e^{in\theta}$. Then $$(*) \quad f(e^{i\alpha} z)= e^{in\alpha} f(z), \quad \forall z\in \mathbb C.$$

Now, let $f$ a Schwartz function on $\mathbb C^2$,

Now, can we hope to find a Schwartz function $f$ on $\mathbb C^2$ who to check the analog of $(*)$ in $\mathbb C^2$ for the harmonic spherical function $Y_m^p(l)$; $l\in \mathbb S^3$, i.e., the following identity 
$$(**) \quad f(l. z)= Y_m^p(l) f(z), \quad \forall z\in \mathbb C^2 \, ??$$
Thank you in advance